# Is pushforward probability measure absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space and $X$ is a real-valued random variable. Then, pushforward probability by $X$ is: $X_* \mathbb P ( \cdot ) = \mathbb 
 P(X^{-1}(\cdot))$. Let $m$ be Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$.

As the title of the question says, if pushforward measure $X_* \mathbb P$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $m$, then by Radon-Nikodym there exists a probability density function $f = \frac{d(X_* \mathbb P)}{d m}$ (of course, I need to assume $\sigma$-finiteness of pushforward measure).

However, this only makes sense if $X_* \mathbb P$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $m$. Is there a reason that pushforward probability is absolutely continuous with respect to $m$?

Comment: No, there's no reason it needs to be the case push-forward measure $\ll m$. See discrete random variables versus continuous random variables versus those which are neither.

Comment: indeed you can see that $X_*\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure, so in particular it is $\sigma $-finite

Comment: Could you clarify _why_ you would expect that the push forward be absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure? The question seems to imply that this is something you expect to be true in general (while in fact that isn’t so). But the question doesn’t make clear where this intuition is coming from. It could be interesting to discuss, rather than just getting the answer that it isn’t true :)

Comment: @postylem I was thinking that way since we usually assume $X$ is a Borel function, instead of measurable function. We could get a lot of wicked examples such as Cantor functions, but I thought we could get some "nice properties" if we limit ourselves to Borel functions. But I guess I was wrong.